# Why is there no scrollbar when an element overflows on the top border?

Tags: html, css, web, overflow

Given an absolutely positioned element with a certain size and `overflow:auto` and a child element that is also absolutely positioned, anchored to the bottom left corner of the parent element and exceeding it in size, like this:

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200%;
}
```

Why does no vertical scrollbar appear on the parent element?

When I change the positioning of the child element to top instead of bottom, the scrollbar appears. It seems like the scrollbar is only visible if the content overflows on the bottom edge of the parent element. Why is this the case?

Here is the link to a JSFiddle that demonstrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/qGsd3/14/

Comment: You can't force overflow to the top ...

Comment: I can see that, but I'm curious why.

Comment: The spec seems to say it should handle overflow from the top, http://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#overflow-properties   perhaps this is a bug. I have a feeling that something about the absolute positioning is what's throwing it off, something about being positioned on top forces flow down but flow can't be forced up the same way so you don't get a scroll

Comment: It is not a bug, see my answer.

Comment: Additional it also happens with overflow left. This is same as the default scroll of the body: http://jsfiddle.net/sEqCw/ Maybe that is why the mouse does not overflow on the top and left side of the screen? ^^ I think they just followed the OS functionality: http://superuser.com/questions/397476/why-the-mouse-cursor-can-pass-the-right-border-of-the-screen-and-not-the-left-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was hoping for a more interesting answer, but it seems to be: "Because the spec says so."

EDIT: I just realized that isn't the right section... But luckily I found the correct one so the answer stands.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/WD-css3-box-20070809/#abs-non-replaced-width

At the bottom there are the rules that dictate when height is calculated and how and it states only when there is overflow on the bottom does it extend the height. There is more reading there about how this affects overflow, so just poke around.

Comment: Can you add an excerpt (edited as needed for clarity) of the rules that says as such?

Answer (score -1):

Absolute elements don't take up any space, that's why. Absolute positioning isn't needed for your content, change it to static, I can't understand what you are trying to accomplish there...

Comment: not true, absolute positioning removes the element from the flow, but they do take up space, look at the  fiddle, it demonstrates this quite well

Comment: I guess this is rather a communication and expression problem rather than a 'semantically' correct answer. anyway

Comment: I just noticed this behaves differently for the top and bottom edges (see the linked JSFiddle for a side-by-side comparison). There's nothing I'm trying to fix.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, nesting an absolute position inside another absolute position has given me nothing but headaches. Also, for heights, percentages can be hit or miss depending on the browser. Take a look here to see what I did on the 'bad' class to display the overflow.

```
#container {
position: relative;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
overflow: auto;
background: green;
text-align: right;
top: 100px;
}
.left {
left: 100px;
}
.right {
left: 300px;
}
#content {
position: absolute;
width: 50%;
height: 100px;
background: red;
}
.good {
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
.bad {
bottom: -20px;
left: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qGsd3/39/

Comment: This does not answer the question asked, he's not trying to fix anything, just asking "why"